# Elixir Ecto - How to Upsert/Increment

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a model that I would like to execute in Phoenix/Elixir. The model basically computes a rolling sum of the amount spent by a user. The model (`Receipts`) looks like the following:

```
---------------
| ID | Amount |
---------------
| 1  |   0    |
| ...|  ...   |
| 5  |   4    |
---------------
```

There is a unique index on `ID`. I want to insert a user into the table (I define the ID) and then set the amount if the user does not exists, otherwise add the new amount to the existing amount. For example, executing:

```
Repo.insert(Users.changeset(%Users{}, %{ID: 1, Amount: 10})
```

Would result in:

```
---------------
| ID | Amount |
---------------
| 1  |   11   |
| ...|  ...   |
| 5  |   4    |
---------------
```

and executing Repo.insert(%Users{}, Users.changeset(%{ID: 6, Amount: 5}) would result in:

```
---------------
| ID | Amount |
---------------
| 1  |   11   |
| ...|  ...   |
| 5  |   4    |
| 6  |   5    |
---------------
```

I know that I should be doing something with `:on_conflict` but I'm a bit lost how to get it right. Can anyone point me in the right way?

Answer (score 12):

Sure, that's possible. It would look something like this:

```
iex> amount_to_add = 10
10
iex> Repo.get(User, 1)
nil
iex> Repo.insert(%User{id: 1, amount: amount_to_add}, conflict_target: :id, on_conflict: [inc: [amount: amount_to_add]])
...
iex> Repo.get(User, 1)
%User{id: 1, amount: 10, ...}
iex> Repo.insert(%User{id: 1, amount: amount_to_add}, conflict_target: :id, on_conflict: [inc: [amount: amount_to_add]])
...
iex> Repo.get(User, 1)
%User{id: 1, amount: 20, ...}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Repo.transaction fn ->
  user =
    User
    |> where(id: ^id)
    |> lock("FOR UPDATE")
    |> Repo.one()

  if user do
    user
    |> change(amount: user.amount + 5)
    |> Repo.update!()
  else
    %User{}
    |> change(amount: 5)
    |> Repo.insert!()
  end
end
```

That's one way to go which uses postgreSQL syntax for locking. I guess you will figure out the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the first answer 
return the variable after the update will prevent parallel problems.

```
iex> Repo.insert(%User{id: 1, amount: amount_to_add},  returning: [:amount], conflict_target: :id, on_conflict: [inc: [amount: amount_to_add]])
```